# Program gets stuck at finding the Contour while using Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, camera, detection, hsv

I recently started using Python and I've been working on an Open CV based project for over a month now.

I am using Simple Thresholding to detect a coloured blob and I have thresholded the HSV values to detect the blob. All works well, but when the blob goes out of the FOV of the camera, the program gets stuck. I was wondering if there could be a while/if condition that I can add at the top of the loop in order to skip the whole loop in case the blob goes outside FOV of the camera and then enter the loop when the blob returns.

Would really appreciate your help on this one! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop and check if the blob region is not null and then find contours!
it would be helpful if you posted your code. We can explain the answer in a better way then.